# JSON could not be decoded while extracting Json contents in Python POST

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, geojson

I'm trying to extract some elements from my Json data passed through an Ajax call to my views.py in Python Django.

My ajax call in my js file looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
          url: "update/",
          data: {'edited': editedFeature},
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          success: function(data){
             alert(data);
          }
       });
```

I'll note here that I'm working on Leaflet layers and that *editedFeature* in the data attribute is of GeoJson value:

```
var editedFeature = selectedFeature.toGeoJSON();
```

My ***views.py*** simply looks like this to test things out:

```
def update(request):
  #ajax data
    line = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    rid = line['rid']

    print(rid)
    print("testing edited route")
  return HttpResponse("Success!")
```

I'm not quite sure if this is correct as I just tried some solutions available in stackoverflow for the similar case. An error occurs stating:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

If I change it to `line = json.loads(request.body)`:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

When clearly if I direcly print out `print(request.body)` this string would show up:

> edited%5Btype%5D=Feature&edited%5Bid%5D=J1276&edited%5Bgeometry%5D%5Btype%5D=LineString&edited%5Bgeometry%5D%5Bcoordinates%5D%5B0%5D%5B%5D=120.965&edited%5Bgeometry%5D%5Bcoordinates%5D%5B0%5D%5B%5D=14.5999&edited%5Bgeometry%5D%5Bcoordinates%5D%5B1%5D%5B%5D=120.964&edited%5Bgeometry%5D%5Bcoordinates%5D%5B1%5D%5B%5D=14.6017&edited%5Bgeometry%5D%5Bcoordinates%5D%5B2%5D%5B%5D=120.963&edited%5Bgeometry%5D%5Bcoordinates%5D%5B2%5D%5B%5D=14.6028&edited%5Bgeometry%5D%5Bcoordinates%5D%5B3%5D%5B%5D=120.962&...
>   %5D%5Bcoordinates%5D%5B9%5D%5B%5D=14.6101&edited%5Bproperties%5D%5Bname%5D=South+Pier+-+Pier+North+via+Del+Pan

I'm wondering why it won't decode or load if there is something in `request.body`? and another thing, how can I for example get `name` from the json string? Is the line `rid = line['rid']` correct?

Comment: The string is not JSON. You should check your ajax settings to use JSON and not GET paramters.

Comment: hi @elyashiv what do you mean by not GET parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to elyashiv, I was able to determine what I was passing to my view and found the solution. From my ajax call I should've made the code like this:

```
     $.ajax({
         url: "/plexus/load-map/update/",
         data: JSON.stringify(editedFeature),
         dataType: 'json',
         type: 'POST',
         contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
         success: function(data){
             alert(data);
         }
     });
```

> data: JSON.stringify(editedFeature),

I was actually passing a string query or something like that from above

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a query string instead of a JSON - if you will decode the string you got ([with this site, for example](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)) you will see it's a banch of values separated by & - just like sending the data in the url. You need to parse it as one.

Comment: thanks for helping me determine what kind of data I'm passing here. I'll check on it :)

Comment: You can use firebug for debugging - it can show you ajax requests, along with more data usefull for web-development.

Comment: Thanks again @elyashiv, found the fix after you helping me determine what type of data I'm getting. Revised it with this: ` data: JSON.stringify(editedFeature),`

Answer (score 0):

***(Updated on September 1, 2020)**

The key is to pass the data object as a string.

```
data: JSON.stringify({'edited': editedFeature}),
```

This will solve for the error on NodeJS as well.